# Facets of the Birkhoff polytope

Tags: geometry, permutations, polytopes, discrete-geometry, birkhoff-polytopes

I recently became interested in the geometric structure of the Birkhoff polytope since it's connected to a problem that I'm working on. [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_polytope) states that the Birkhoff polytope has $n^2$ facets, but doesn't explain the partitioning actually works. So I'm wondering how I can determine which vertices (which are permutation matrices) belong to the same facet.

The only clue that I've found comes from the paper "Faces of the Birkhoff Polytope", which says

> The facets of the Birkhoff polytope are precisely defined by the inequalities $x_{ij} \geq 0$ for $1 \leq i, j \leq n$.

While this makes sense for continuous points, I'm not sure how to relate the inequality to find the vertices of the facets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the facets lie in the hyperplanes $x_{ij}=0$, the facet corresponding to $x_{ij}$ contains all vertices that have $x_{ij}=0$, i.e. the permutation matrices that correspond to permutations that don't map $j$ to $i$. There are $(n-1)(n-1)!$ of these. (Pick one of the other $n-1$ elements to map $j$ to and then count the possible images of the remaining elements as usual.)

By the way, the Wikipedia article also states that the facets are defined by the non-negativity constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you happen to know if there is a way to determine the facets of the facets as well? I'm interested in a recursive relationship specifically for the Birkhoff polytope.

Comment: There was a comment posted here earlier saying that a facet of a facet occurs where two facets intersect. I'm not sure why it was removed, since it seemed correct.

Comment: I got stuck at the claim quoted in the question. How do the inequalities $x_{ij} \geq 0$ determine the facets of the Birkhoff polytopes?